# How do i know my iAd will work after release in AppStore?

Tags: ios, iad

I am finishing my AppStore Game with an iAd Banner. I already included the iAd framework. In my Game ViewController I placed a iAd BannerView. The following is my code:

in Game.h

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

in Game.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[...]
[super viewDidLoad];
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
```

In simulator and on my iPhone I get this result on the following photo:

http://s1.directupload.net/images/140506/scgmg5nf.png
(Sorry - I need at least 10 reputations to post images directly.)

I think every things looking fine, but will this iAd BannerView display real adverts after release? I don't know whats an indicator for working without problems.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.  Hopefully my answer below answered your question.  If it did, please click on the check mark to accept the answer.  This will allow others to know that an answer exists to the question. This gives us both rep points, which will allow you to post images and such.  Also, if others see that you have accepted an answer, they are more likely to help in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you are on the right track. The test iAd is displaying properly. On a device it will look green if the frame is set fine too. Just remember that after your app gets approved it will take a couple days for the ads to appear. My last app took 3 days for ads to start. Hope this helps.